# How to get the TValue List<> of Dictionary<>

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<>` that's set up as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> srt = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

and I would like to access a specific string in the `List<string>` (which is the `TValue` in the `Dictionary<>`
)**.**

For example -> Given: `Dictionary<1, {"string1", "string2", "string3"}>`, how can I access "string2", and only "string2" specifically.

I hope the question was clear enough to understand. If it wasn't, tell me what I need to clarify.
Thanks!

Comment: Not really... what do you mean by "access string2"? You could use `srt[1][1]` to get at `"string2"` as a value, but I've no idea whether that's what you're trying to achieve, or whether you know either of the 1 values there (the first being the dictionary key, the second being the index within the list)

Comment: you have to search through all of collections to find "string2". perhaps you should consider redesign your data structure to achieve higher performance and direct access.

Comment: Is there any logic based on which you want to access the second list-item of the first key-value-pair in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
 dict .Add(1, new List<string> { "Hello", "World" });

 string result = fileList[1][1]; //Will output "World"
```

Comment: So I guess what I was missing was that `dict[1]` collapses to the `List<string>`, which in turn let's me add another `[1]` as the List's index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 var concreteValue = str.Values.SelectMany(l => l.Where(v => v.Equals("string2")))
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This accesses the item whose key is 1, which is what OP has already shown as an example.

Comment: That's still unnecessary and loops through each Dictionary item, and each List. `string string2 = str[1][1]`

Comment: Yes I know, but I think that OP want to retrieve value without knowing exact key value

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var res = srt[1][0]; //"string1"
```

First index is a key and second index refers to list element

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually. Access by key to the specific list then you can treat it as an array. The syntax would be ***srt[key][index]***

Which means to access string2 specifically you need write as `var b = srt[1][1];` here ***b*** will have string2